# Function to exit a parent function

Tags: javascript

I have a loop that runs indefinitely until I tell it to stop. I am actually using requestAnimationFrame and a lot more is going on, but the below example is just to simplify my question.

```
var _stop = false;

var loop = function () {
    while (!_stop) {
        if (some condition is met) {
            stop();
        }

        /* Do something. */

        loop();
    }
};

function stop() {
    _stop = true;
}
```

Now this all works great, but it will still run `/* Do something */` one more time before it actually stops. I want it to stop immediately and return.
Of course this can be done like so:

```
if (some condition is met) {
    stop();
    return;
}
```

But is there a way to include the `return` part into `stop();`? This doesn't do what I want for obvious reasons:

```
function stop() {
    _stop = true;
    return;
}
```

But is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not `stop(); return;` from inside the `loop`?

Comment: I do right now, and it works, but my question was if there is a way to have `stop();` do the `return` part for me. But maybe there isn't.

Comment: The closest I can see you getting is by using `return stop();` to combine it into one line.

Comment: That is actually not bad @GregL. Closer to what I wanted to accomplish and might be satisfactory. I just want it to be simple to understand for a non-coder that only has access to the scope inside the loop, and it doesn't get much simpler than just `stop();`, but `return stop();` might just be good enough since there doesn't seem to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _stop = false;
try {
  var loop = function () {
      if(!_stop) {
          if (some condition is met) {
              stop();
          }

          /* Do something. */

          loop();
      }
  };
} catch(e) {

}
function stop() {
    _stop = true;
    throw new Error("USE IT WITH PRECAUTION");
}
```

The loop above does you job of exiting entire loop, But I will say its horribly wrong way of doing thing as ideally function should be

1) mutating the state variables

2) or should be computing the values.

3) or should be determining error state to stop the execution further

It should never be bothered about how the control flow of function caller is and ways to stop function caller execution flow.

Comment: Hah, very creative! But I wouldn't dare calling this the correct answer. By now, I believe the correct answer is something like *"No, it doesn't work"*.

Comment: that's why I said in "USE IT WITH PRECAUTION" :>

Comment: Upvote for hilarious reasons. It actually does exactly what I was asking for, but the ends doesn't always justify the means.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check the condition (before) every time the work is done.  To do this with a _stop variable (as opposed to simply checking the condition in the while condition itself), you have to:

- Set the variable based on the condition before starting the loop
- Do your work
- Set the variable based on the condition before the next loop iteration

Whether you accomplish this with a while() loop or a do while() loop, the process will be the same.  Adding a pre-loop check to your example will prevent the work from being done if the user has already exited:

```
var _stop = false;

// Call loop() when required

var loop = function () {

    // Check condition before first iteration
    if (/* some condition is met */) {
        stop();
    }

    while (!_stop) {

        /* Do your work */

        // Check condition before every subsequent iteration
        if (/* some condition is met */) {
            stop();
        }

    loop();

    }
};

function stop() {
    _stop = true;
}
```

Is there a reason you are recursively calling loop() instead of calling it once and doing all of your work within the contained loop until the user exits?  This more simplified version might work for you:

```
var _stop = false; // Set it initially, could also use checkStopRequired() here

// Call loop() when required

var loop = function () {

    // Check condition before first iteration
    _stop = checkStopRequired();

    while (!_stop) {

        // Do your work, setting _stop to true if work returns early
        _stop = !doMyWork();

        // Check condition before every subsequent iteration
        _stop = checkStopRequired();

    }
};

function checkStopRequired() {
    // Return true if should stop, false if should continue
}
```

When doing the work required for each loop iteration, you may want to check the exit condition before any expensive operations to allow the whole thing to halt as soon as an exit condition is met, as opposed to waiting for the work to finish.  This obviously depends on what work you're doing and what the exit conditions are.

An example of the function to be called within the loop, which will help you set _stop if the stop condition is met part-way through:

```
function doMyWork() {
    // Get user input here...

    if (checkStopRequired()) { return false; }

    // Get data here...

    if (checkStopRequired()) { return false; }

    // Do logic here...

    if (checkStopRequired()) { return false; }

    // Render objects here...

    // Return successful result
    return true;

}
```

Comment: The loop in my example is actually a requestAnimationFrame, hence the reson for the recursion. I wanted to leave requestAnimationFrame out of it for simplification, but I have come to realise from the answers that this might have been a mistake. As far as I can see, your solution still permits things to happen between the point that the conditions are met and the point where they are checked to see if they are met. The only solution I can see if `stop();` can somehow just break / exit / return on the spot, but that doesn't seem to be possible without `stop(); return;`.

Comment: I have updated my example to check the condition as often as you want. Without using errors/exceptions, you'll have to poll the state of the stop condition between bits of code that do the work. A single return statement at any point in doMyWork() will stop doMyWork() and set the flag, which stops the loop before any further code is executed. While it's not exactly what you've asked for, which I don't believe is possible without using errors/exceptions, this solution lets you kill the whole thing in one line by either setting _stop in the loop or returning false in the work function.

Answer (score -1):

it might not be the optimal way to do this, but this can be done like this:

```
var _stop = false;
var flag=0;
var loop = function () {
    if(!_stop) {
        if(flag){
           return;
        }
        if (some condition is met) {
            stop();
            _stop = true;
            loop();
        }

        /* Do something. */

        loop();
    }
};

function stop() {
    //_stop = true;
    toReturn();
}

function toReturn(){
    flag=1;
}
```

Comment: That would not `return` until the next iteration, executing `/* Do something */` when it shouldn't

Comment: after calling **stop();** by adding **_stop = true;**  and **loop();** again can solve this and **/* Do something */** won't execute..

Comment: While this might work, I can just do `stop(); return` today, and I want to shorten in to just `stop();`. I just want my end user to be able to type `stop();` anywhere inside the loop and it stops, and this complicated it even more. Thanks though!